# how to add specific column related to other column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

i want to add specific column that related to other column in dataframe

this is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'index': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'], 
    'charac' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B']})
```

When it's the same in 'charac', it goes on continuously.
but it's different in 'charac', it starts again

like this `'add_col' = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3]`

i think it can be work with 'for' but i don't know how to do .... 
could you tell me the answer ..?

Comment: can you provide us the desirable result (dataframe) ?

Comment: What is .. **When it's the same in 'charac', it goes on continuously. but it's different in 'charac', it starts again**

Comment: `df['add_col'] = df.groupby('charac').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: oh my god! Quang Hoang _ thank you so much.... !!!! it works thank you